# Error - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, side-by-side

My exe built on Visual studio 2008 runs on my development system but on other systems it gives the error "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. please..." The exe is in release mode and I have installed the VC redistributable.

Using dumpbin /dependents command I see that it along with other dlls it is also dependent on msvcr90d.dll I think this could be the reason I am getting this error. In project properties - cc++- code generation - runtime library i have selected MultiThreaded dll (/MD)

Any suggestions on how to remove this dependency or finally how to fix the error?

Thanks,Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

You might have compiled your app using "Debug" settings, which adds a dependency on the debug C++ runtime, which wouldn't be present on other systems. You want to compile as "Release" if you want to take a dependency on the release C++ runtime. The release runtime may nor may not be present on other systems, so it must be bundled with your program. You can read more about that in the "redist.txt" file located in the Visual Studio installation directory.